# How to count how many times you run a macro

Tags: vba, excel

I need to **count** everytime I run a macro. Currently, this is what I'm doing:

```
Public i As Integer

Sub Macro5()

i = i + 1

Cells(5, 5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & i // printing the i in 5,5 cell

End Sub
```

But everytime I run Macro5 again, the i sets to 1 (0 at first, but adding 1 to it making it 1).
Any idea how I can count it? Thanks!

Comment: instead of i = i +1 you can get value in the cell and adding 1. Something like this i = Cells(5, 5).Value + 1 (not sure if this is correct syntax but I think you get the point)

Comment: @Dave, what Erik told will do the trick you are looking for

Comment: @ErikBlomgren It stays 2 the whole time... :( I did [ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & (i+1) ] but everytime i becomes 0 again so it stays 2... Any other idea?

Comment: Well, your code works fine on my machine

Comment: @Siva I thought like you, but it stays 2 after adding 1 to it... Any help? :)

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 Does it matter where I declare the global "i"? I declared it between to macros. Doesn't metter, right?

Comment: You must put the global variables on top of your code module to make them work properly

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 That's correct! Working now! Thank you very much.

Comment: @ErikBlomgren I didn't declare the i in the proper place. Working just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave, why not directly, add one to `Cells(5,5)` every time, you can simple type `Cells(5,5).Value = Cells(5,5).Value+1` i guess you needn't have any `i` and formula required there. Think and let me know if i'm missing any logic here

Comment: @Siva Your code is logical and correct, but I need to use the "i" as a global variable, in some other macro. Thanks though!

Comment: @Dave, Thanks for clarifying. Happy coding !!!

Comment: @Siva Oh! Thank you so much. :) Another question, if I may. I want to declare a starting value to the i. How can I do it?

Comment: Just to add on the cell writing part that you can simply go:  Cells(5, 5) = i

Comment: @Dave, Anytime you may,if i understood you correct, Inside your subroutine, assign it a value`i=0` before `i=i+1` is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Siva In the end it wasn't what I needed at all haha. Thanks! I am so sorry to bother you but one thing is not working for me, there is a cell that is set to "text", and everytime I try to put info there it's just copying the whole code line, =[7.xlsx]sheet1!R" & i & "C2 . Any idea how to fix it? When I return the cell to "general", it's working. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dave, it may be due to the cell formatting. I guess the Format of the cell is 'Text'. That could be the reason, why the code is copying. Try changing the format of the cell to 'General' or any other format as per your expectations

Comment: @Siva yeah, the formatting is text. That's what I meant at the beginning (my English isn't so good haha). Though I need it as a "Text". Do we have a solution?

Comment: @Siva I'm actualy storaging numbers but in the beginning of some of them there is 0. If there's a better way saving them it would be even better haha!

Comment: @Siva Well if you choose the format right under the "coins" one, it will work. Thank you for all your help! Realy appriciate it.

Comment: @Dave, im not sure, what i can suggest is just convert the formatting to General via code at first, after assigning the code line, you can change the format back to Text(as you want), regarding 0, may be you can have If condition on your code line some thing like  `=If( your code line <>"", your code line,"")` so whenever value is 0, it will fill with empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work fine provided you declare the global variable `i` outside the sub-routine and on the top of your code module.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, this would be the correct one.

```
Sub Macro5()

Cells(5, 5).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to have some number set initially for cell E5.

Comment: Thanks :) Though I need the i var to use in other function. Thanks again!